# How do I find data that helps US businesses export their products?

Tags: data-request, usa, business, trade

Are there data sets out there that have data about exporting products and services overseas?  I want to build an app that helps U.S. businesses increase their international sales.

Answer (score 3):

The International Trade Administration (ITA) has just released Version 2 of all of its APIs on its [Data Services Platform](http://developer.trade.gov/).  This means developers can access even more export data, more easily.

Here are the updates

1. **New Data:**  You asked and we answered!  We are now providing access
   to:

   - Tariff Rates from all US Free Trade Agreements
   - FAQs About Exporting.
2. **More Data:** We are adding more data to our existing data sets:

   - Additional screening lists
   - Trade Events from more trade agencies
   - Overseas opportunities from FedBizOpps
3. **Friendlier:**  We’ve made it easier and more secure for developers to get the data they are looking for.

You can learn more about the details on [ITA's wiki](https://github.com/InternationalTradeAdministration/developerportal/wiki/Version-2-of-ITA%E2%80%99s-Data-Services-Platform-Released).